# How can I add server-side validation to an unknown quantity of controls?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have a form with a variable quantity of questions based on a database value.

The form is generated at runtime. All the questions are in the same multi-line format.

> Question 1
>
> Textbox for answer
>
> Question 2
>
> Textbox for answer
>
> ...

For each answer, I must validate the output and provide a customized validation message. e.g.

> You have provided the following invalid characters: (...)

I was able to generate a custom validator for each of the controls for client-side validation.

I was trying to reuse the concept for server-side validation, but the options don't seem to be available. I don't see how to write a Validator_ServerValidate function if I don't know the name or quantity of validators before runtime.

How can I add server-side validation to an unknown quantity of controls?